# Can't View FTP Directory in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ftp

I just upgraded to Google Chrome v73.0.3683.103 and I am now unable to view FTP sites in Chrome. Instead of Chrome loading the FTP directory listing in the browser, it downloads a file named `download` which contains a directory listing.

How do I get the ability to view the FTP directories directly in Chrome back?

I have tried going into Internet Options > Advanced and clicking on the "Enable FTP folder view (outside of Internet Explorer)" but, that didn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In-browser FTP was deprecated back in v72. I hadn't updated Chrome in a few releases. I have rolled back to v71 until I find a better workflow substitute

DETAILS: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/12/chrome-72-deps-rems

Comment: That page says "Chrome will still generate directory listings".

Comment: Correct. If you read the original question, I was trying to figure out why Chrome wouldn't display the FTP directories in-browser anymore.

Comment: Which means that "can't view FTP directory listings" is an unintended consequence of this and you might wish to file a bug.